# Why does Python 2 allow .encode() on string objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

In Python 2, you can call `str.decode` to get a unicode object, and `unicode.encode` to get a str object.

```
>>> "foo".decode('utf-8')
u'foo'
>>> u"foo".encode('utf-8')
'foo'
```

Python 3 is similar, using `bytes.decode` to get a string, and `str.encode` to get a bytes object.

```
>>> "foo".encode('utf-8')
b'foo'
>>> b"foo".decode('utf-8')
'foo'
```

However, Python 2 (but not Python 3) also provides methods the wrong way around: you can call `.encode` on a `str` object, or `.decode` on a unicode object!

```
>>> "foo".encode('utf-8')
'foo'
>>> u"foo".decode('utf-8')
u'foo'
```

Why is this? Is there any time that it is useful to call `.decode` on a unicode object, or vice versa?

Comment: It's a sign telling you to switch to Python 3 :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in Python 2, the thought was that you would want to treat text in byte strings (`str` objects) and Unicode strings (`unicode` objects) interchangeably, transparently. When a bytestring is expected, `unicode` objects are transparently encoded (to ASCII), and conversely, when Unicode is expected, a `str` object is transparently decoded, assuming ASCII again.

So `str.encode()` will first *decode*, then encode again. Or `unicode.decode()` will *encode* first, to then decode the result.

There is only a use for this if your code wants to accept either `str` or `unicode` objects and treat these interchangeably. So a function that expects a bytestring and attempts to decode that bytestring will continue to work, even if you pass in a `unicode` object containing only ASCII codepoints.

This led to a huge amount of confusion and errors (just search for `UnicodeEncodeError` and `UnicodeDecodeError` here on Stack Overflow), so in Python 3 the types were dis-entangled.